# Fast construction of STL map

Tags: c++, stl, dictionary

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to convert a sorted std::list of std::pair to a std::map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3412623/how-to-convert-a-sorted-stdlist-of-stdpair-to-a-stdmap)
>   [Is the STL map container optimized (balanced tree) while constructed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10428342/is-the-stl-map-container-optimized-balanced-tree-while-constructed)

Since a balanced binary search tree can be quickly (`O(n)`) constructed from a sorted list of elements, and STL `map` is (in practice even if not by definition) implemented as a tree, is there some way to insert all the elements of a sorted container into a map in `O(n)` instead of the `O(nLogn)` guaranteed by `map::insert`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is the STL map container optimized (balanced tree) while constructed?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10428342/is-the-stl-map-container-optimized-balanced-tree-while-constructed) or [How to convert a sorted std::list of std::pair to a std::map](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3412623/how-to-convert-a-sorted-stdlist-of-stdpair-to-a-stdmap)